# attribute error when try to define url for index view

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

I keep getting a strange error when I define urls:

```
AttributeError at /
'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:51942/
Django Version: 2.1.3
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
```

here is my urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from saeed import views


urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('', views.index, name="index"),


]
```

and here is my views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    return render,"index.html"
```

Please inform me.
thanks,
Saeed

Comment: `render` is a function. `return render,"index.html"` returns a tuple. Pass the html file to the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your view to:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")
```